# How do i use XPATH properly in scrapy?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/asset_report_dtl.aspx?lflag=eng&state_name=WEST%20BENGAL&state_code=32&district_name=NADIA&district_code=3201&block_name=KRISHNAGAR-I&block_code=&panchayat_name=DOGACHI&panchayat_code=3201009009&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=8+kWKUdwzDQA1IJ5qhD8Fw

Above is the link of the page

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bhzV.png

The red marked box number is what I am trying to get through xpath

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mca05.png

The red marked box is the inspect line of that same item. my code is below

```
**scrapy shell**

**fetch("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/asset_report_dtl.aspx?lflag=eng&state_name=WEST%20BENGAL&state_code=32&district_name=NADIA&district_code=3201&block_name=KRISHNAGAR-I&block_code=&panchayat_name=DOGACHI&panchayat_code=3201009009&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=8+kWKUdwzDQA1IJ5qhD8Fw")**

**assetid = response.xpath("//div[3]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")**

**assetid**

**[]**(This is what it returns.)

**assetid = response.xpath("//div[3]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()")**(I tried this also)

**assetid**

**[]**(This is what it returns.)
```

when is use view(response) it says true & opens the same page in browser.

My code is below

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAf38.png

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTWwH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say get end of the xpath you will print what you expect also I update your xpath too:

instead this:

```
assetid = response.xpath("//div[3]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
```

use this:

```
assetid = response.xpath('//table[2]//tr[4]/td[2]/text()').get()
```

I hope it will works.

Comment: assetid = response.xpath('//table[2]//tr[4]/td[2]/text()').get()   this one worked, while i tried the same with   assetid = response.xpath("//div[3]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()").get()    this did not worked. I dont understand where did my xpath went wrong. thanx though for the help.

Comment: when I print `response.text` there was no div. Scrapy getting response body statically it could cause. Generally `//table//some tr,td` works more efficient.